# integration by parts

Tags: integration

**!!!!  PD: I did a little change in the denominator  !!!!**

I need to solve this integral using integration by parts.

$\displaystyle\int\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)+(x-c)^2}}$

Thanks!

PS: I know that I can to do:

$\displaystyle\int\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)+(x-c)^2}}=\int\frac{(x-c)\,dx}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)+(x-c)^2}}+c\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)+(x-c)^2}}$

but according to the book it is easier using integration by part.

Comment: That looks like a trig substitution.

Comment: Using the idea in "PS" is easy using trig substitution, but I need use integration by parts. According to the book is the easier way.

Comment: Consider the possibility that the book is wrong. Not that it necessarily means much, but I don't see how integration by parts would make it easier.

Comment: sorry. I did a little change in the denominator.

Comment: What does "PD" mean?  The change in the denominator doesn't affect the problem.  Whether it's $a^2+b^2$ or $(a^2+b^2)^2$, it's just a positive number, which you could call $k^2$ if it makes your life easier. (I guess you want to handle $a=b=0$ separately.)

Comment: PD = P.D.: post data (just to emphasize that the change was after sending the message).

Comment: Thats true Jonas :)

Comment: Simplify everything by letting $a^2+b^2 = k$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x-c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \tan \theta,$ then $d x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sec ^2 \theta d \theta$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x d x}{\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2\right)+(x-c)^2}} &=\int \frac{c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2 \tan \theta}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2 \sec \theta}} \sqrt{a^2+b^2 \sec ^2 \theta} d \theta\\
&=\int\left(c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \tan \theta\right) \sec \theta d \theta \\
&=c \ln |\sec \theta+\tan \theta|+\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sec \theta+C\\
&=c \ln \left|\frac{x-c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right|+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need integration by parts. First, observe the following:

$$\left[\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}\right]'=\frac {x-c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}$$

Integrating both sides and isolating the integral under question gives

$$\int\frac x{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}+c\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}$$

The latter integral can be evaluated using an Euler Substitution. A more detailed explanation of how to perform an Euler Substitution can be found on the Wikipedia page, but the substitution to make here is

$$t=x-c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}$$

Differentiating gives

\begin{align*}
\mathrm dt & =1+\frac {x-c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\ & =\frac {x-c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\ & =\frac t{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align*}

As in

$$\frac {\mathrm dt}t=\frac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}$$

The integral is then

\begin{align*}
 & \int\frac x{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\ & =\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}+c\int\frac {\mathrm dt}t\\ & =\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}+c\log\left(x-c+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+(x-c)^2}\right)+K
\end{align*}